# how to update email template from backend for custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2

**My custom module file is showing in the drop down (marketing -> email template) but when i add and update the code it is not showing up in email**[image]

Answer (score 0):

For changing template, you need to create one system config under **Stores -> Configuration**. Ex.

Open the following file:

***vendor/magento/module-contact/etc/adminhtml/system.xml***

Now check following code, how system config create for template:

```
<field id="email_template" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
    <label>Email Template</label>
    <comment>Email template chosen based on theme fallback when "Default" option is selected.</comment>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
    <depends>
        <field id="*/contact/enabled">1</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

After add/modify the template from **marketing -> email template**, you can change your template from system config from admin.